# I cloned source code of Mayan EDMS from git repo and getting issues of static files during local setup

Tags: mayanedms

I cloned the mayan-edms source code from the git. The server is running absolutely fine and documents are uploading but documents are not showing on the front-end. I think the issue is with Redis queues. It shows this message `New document queued for upload and will be available shortly`. I think this issue is related to Redis queues and I tried to set celery worker locally in Mayan but it couldn't run. Does anybody know about this issue of Mayan?

Comment: problem is solved, there were different environment settings,  for development purpose we need to setup development base file and add all the configurations of celery, Redis in `development/base.py` file. This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the command `python manage.py initialsetup`. This will solve my issue with running Mayan source code locally, other than that you need to check all the queues and the status of those queues.